# How are jersey numbers assigned in Cricket?

Tags: rules, cricket, uniform

It is quite normal in international cricket matches(Test/ODI/T20) that players are having a particular Jersey number assigned to them. Some of the famous players such as Ricky Ponting always wears number 14, while Sachin Tendulkar wears number 10. So the question is who assigns these numbers and on what basis are these allocated? Is it on first come first serve basis? Are there some procedure followed for this?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no standard system, probably because the use of jersey numbers is a relatively new phenomenon in cricket, so there is no history upon which conventions have been built. As you suggest, big name players typically get to wear whatever they like another example being Shane Warne who always wears 23, the same as Michael Jordan wore in Basketball.

Answer (score 4):

A recent newspaper article said that players can choose any number they want, as long as no one else in the team has taken it first.
For example, Rohit Sharma wanted the number 10 jersey, but he couldn't have it, since a senior player (guess who? :p) already has it.

It is also not compulsory for every player to have a jersey number, for example Virendra Sehwag (in the Indian Jersey - I don't know about IPL).

Comment: Sehwag was like so many relatives/astrologers suggested me different numbers and i better not dissapoint anyone. he went numberless thereafter +D

Answer (score 3):

There some facts or rumors about those jersey numbers as well some people suggest that every number has its special meaning in Numerology such as number 10 means **PERFECT**.
As a part of cricket is taken in mind these numbers are chosen by the big cricketing stars by their own just like 333 for Chris Gayle.

Comment: Could you add some references to support this? I'd be interested to see any articles on special meanings. And welcome to Sports.SE!

Comment: http://numerology-thenumbersandtheirmeanings.blogspot.in/2011/05/number-10.html

Comment: Sorry - I wasn't totally clear. Are there references tying jersey numbers to numerology?

Comment: @SocioMatt Sounds weird, but players are a superstitious bunch and they are prepared to go any length to do well. You can read the "logic" of some jersey numbers being chosen based on numerology [here](http://criczat.com/2011/11/jersey-no-numerology/).

Comment: thanks @Orangecrush i was looking for such reference i was having a reference of other site but i was unable to find it out again as i lost it and can not remeber it for now.

Comment: Chris gayle has 333 probably because that is his highest test score in an innings.

Comment: @kartshan yes you are right and it is the reference for players choosing jersey numbers on there own decision .

Comment: @NetStarter it proves that the players can wish for a number. Not that they choose them completely on their own, there must be some one receiving all their wishes and the deciding whether it's okay.

Answer (score 1):

Without having a source for cricket especially, I would guess that it's the team leaders/coach/manager that decide the players numbers. As far as I know this is normal in all team sports.

The players normally gets to request a number, and in most cases the get their choice if no one else wants it, but in the end it's decided by the leaders.

Answer (score -2):

The Jersey numbers are allotted randomly to players. What happens is when a new team is formed, players usually don't know/remember everyone's name. So they call out Jersey number during the play.
Number 10 gained importance due to pele wearing it. Other countries also started giving number 10 to the best player in the team. Slowly it propagated to other games.

Comment: Welcome to Sports SE, please add reference to your answer before you attract downvotes. Can you justify  "Number 10 gained importance due to Pele wearing it" seems an opinion to me.

Answer (score -5):

I think that they are put in these numbers because they are linked to soccer players for example messi wears number 10 and sachin too and Ronaldo wears 7 and dhoni too